# How did 'knowledge of nature' narrow semantically to: art of healing, medical science?

Tags: étymologie, ancien-français, science, grec

<sub>Cette question est amenée par [celle-ci sur ELU](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/222580/50720). La traduction française se trouve ci-dessous.</sub>

> [physic (n.)](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=physic&allowed_in_frame=0)
> [1.]    c. 1300, *fysike*, "art of healing, **medical science**," also "natural science" (c. 1300),
> [2.] from Old French *fisike* **"natural science, art of healing"** (12c.)
> [3.] and directly from Latin *physica* (fem. singular of *physicus*) "study of nature,"
>
> [4.] from Greek *physike* (*episteme*) **"(knowledge) of nature,"**
> from fem. of *physikos* "pertaining to nature," from *physis* "nature,"
> from *phyein* "to bring forth, produce, make to grow" (related to phyton "growth, plant," phyle "tribe, race," phyma "a growth, tumor")
> from PIE root **bheue-* "to be exist, grow" (see [be](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=be&allowed_in_frame=0)).
> […]

How can [4.] possibly be connected to [1.] and [2.]?  I am uneducated in the history of medicine.
To wit, how did the bolded in [4.]
narrow semantically to mean the bolded in 1 and 2?

---

**French translation:**

Comment est-il possible que [4.] se rapporte à [1.] and [2.] ?
À savoir, comment le gras en dans [4.]
se retrécie-t-il semantiquement  pour signifier :
« medical science » in [1.]  et  « natural science, art of healing » in [2.] ?

Je suis inculte en histoire de la médecine ; veuillez expliciter tous les changements sémantiques dissimulés et manquants.

Comment: cf. http://hsm.stackexchange.com/q/4996/3478

Answer (score 4):

All of these meanings are closely related.

In particular, it is not surprising at all for a root meaning "knowledge of nature" to evolve into words applying to numerous subsets of such a wide concept, like "knowledge of human body and living organisms" (medical science, biology), how to heal them (medical science too), and "knowledge of the elements" (physical science), especially as during the centuries when this word evolved, what are now distant specialties were likely handled by the same persons that we might call generalists today.

Note also that the medical meaning side has faded in French. While it is still there in "*forme physique*", "*éducation physique*", unlike in English, we do not call a doctor a "physician/*physicien*"<sup>1</sup> so we do not need to use "*physiciste*" for a physicist.

<sup>1</sup> Actually we did, *[fisicien](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/fisicien)* was used in the thirteen century French.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but will you please explicate why `it is not surprising at all`? I do not see the connections.

Comment: Living organisms do pertain to nature, aren't they?

Comment: @Làchus'n'AI Ah oui, c'est vrai. Un faux-ami très rare, comme scientiste.

Comment: @jillagre Vous avez raison oui, mais ce rétrécissement me semble trop contraignant et me confond déjà, en ignorant d'autres types de la nature. Pourriez-vous en expliquer plus, SVP ?

Comment: Les mots subissent souvent des évolutions sémantiques au cours du temps. Physique désignait ce que l'on appelle aujourd'hui les sciences naturelles jusqu'à la fin du XVe siècle, où, en tant qu'adjectif, il commença à s'appliquer aux sciences expérimentales modernes, celles de Copernic et Galilée.

Comment: Un sujet vraiment difficile, puisqu'il y avait ça en latin médiéval (voir [_DuCange_](http://ducange.enc.sorbonne.fr/physica) ; notez aussi le passage en français, voir son [manuscrit](http://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/btv1b90604574/f27.item.zoom)/[texte](https://books.google.com/books?redir_esc=y&hl=fr&id=87MBAAAAYAAJ&q=physiciens), page gauche, col. 2, au centre, pour le plaisir.). Enfin de mémoire le _DHLF_ parle d'une dialectique savante _physica/natura_, dans le contexte d'un apport de la mécanique au discours philosophique, et de développements parallèles du masc/fem. des mots...

Answer (score 1):

[Littré](http://www.littre.org/definition/physique) donne de nombreux sens à *physique*, tournant tous autour de la nature et du matériel. Le dernier sens indique que le lien entre physique et médecine date du moyen âge.